# Rectify Exception in JSpeex Encoding

Tags: java

I am getting a null pointer exception. I have seen the previous posts for null pointer exception but I am unable to solve my problem. Also I provided my snapshot of the Exception

Below is my JSpeexCode and SpeexEncoder code.

JSpeex Code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xiph.speex.AudioFileWriter;
import org.xiph.speex.OggSpeexWriter;
import org.xiph.speex.PcmWaveWriter;
import org.xiph.speex.RawWriter;
import org.xiph.speex.SpeexEncoder;

/**
 * Java Speex Command Line Encoder.
 * 
 * Currently this code has been updated to be compatible with release 1.0.3.
 * 
 * @author Marc Gimpel, Wimba S.A. (mgimpel@horizonwimba.com)
 * @version $Revision: 1.5 $
 */
public class JSpeexEnc
{
  /** Version of the Speex Encoder */
  public static final String VERSION = "Java Speex Command Line Encoder v0.9.7 ($Revision: 1.5 $)";
  /** Copyright display String */
  public static final String COPYRIGHT = "Copyright (C) 2002-2004 Wimba S.A.";

  /** Print level for messages : Print debug information */
  public static final int DEBUG = 0;
  /** Print level for messages : Print basic information */
  public static final int INFO  = 1;
  /** Print level for messages : Print only warnings and errors */
  public static final int WARN  = 2;
  /** Print level for messages : Print only errors */
  public static final int ERROR = 3;

    /** Print level for messages */
  protected int printlevel = INFO;

  /** File format for input or output audio file: Raw */
  public static final int FILE_FORMAT_RAW  = 0;
  /** File format for input or output audio file: Ogg */
  public static final int FILE_FORMAT_OGG  = 1;
  /** File format for input or output audio file: Wave */
  public static final int FILE_FORMAT_WAVE = 2;
  /** Defines File format for input audio file (Raw, Ogg or Wave). */
  protected int srcFormat  = FILE_FORMAT_OGG;
  /** Defines File format for output audio file (Raw or Wave). */
  protected int destFormat = FILE_FORMAT_WAVE;

  /** Defines the encoder mode (0=NB, 1=WB and 2=UWB). */
 protected int mode       = -1;
  /** Defines the encoder quality setting (integer from 0 to 10). */
  protected int quality    = 8;
  /** Defines the encoders algorithmic complexity. */
  protected int complexity = 3;
  /** Defines the number of frames per speex packet. */
  protected int nframes    = 1;
  /** Defines the desired bitrate for the encoded audio. */
  protected int bitrate    = -1;
  /** Defines the sampling rate of the audio input. */
  protected int sampleRate  = -1;
  /** Defines the number of channels of the audio input (1=mono, 2=stereo). */
  protected int channels   = 1;
  /** Defines the encoder VBR quality setting (float from 0 to 10). */
  protected float vbr_quality = -1;
  /** Defines whether or not to use VBR (Variable Bit Rate). */
  protected boolean vbr    = false;
  /** Defines whether or not to use VAD (Voice Activity Detection). */
  protected boolean vad    = false;
  /** Defines whether or not to use DTX (Discontinuous Transmission). */
  protected boolean dtx    = false;

  /** The audio input file */
  protected String srcFile;
  /** The audio output file */
  protected String destFile;


  /**
   * Builds a plain JSpeex Encoder with default values.
   */


  /**
   * Command line entrance:
   * <pre>
   * Usage: JSpeexEnc [options] input_file output_file
   * </pre>
   * @param args Command line parameters.
   */



  public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
     {
    JSpeexEnc encoder = new JSpeexEnc();
    if (encoder.parseArgs(args)) {
     encoder.encode("frf1.wav", "frf1_encoded.raw");

     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\workspace\\JSpeex.java\\src\\frf1.wav")))
        {

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
    }
  }

    /**
   * Parse the command line arguments.
   * @param args Command line parameters.
     * @param FILE_FORMAT_WAVE1
   * @return true if the parsed arguments are sufficient to run the encoder.
   */
  public boolean parseArgs(final String[] args)
  {
    // make sure we have command args
    if (args.length < 2) {
      if (args.length==1 && (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-v") || args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("--version"))) {
        version();
        return false;
      }
      usage();
      return false;
    }

    // Determine input, output and file formats
    srcFile = args[args.length-2];
    destFile = args[args.length-1];
    if (srcFile.toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav")) 
    {
         srcFormat = FILE_FORMAT_WAVE;
    }
    else {
      srcFormat = FILE_FORMAT_RAW;
    }
    if (destFile.toLowerCase().endsWith(".spx")) {
      destFormat = FILE_FORMAT_OGG;
    }
    else if (destFile.toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav")) {
        destFormat = FILE_FORMAT_WAVE;
    }
    else {
        destFormat = FILE_FORMAT_RAW;
    }
    // Determine encoder options
    for (int i=0; i<args.length-2; i++) {
      if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-h") || args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--help")) {
        usage();
        return false;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-v") || args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--version")) {
        version();
        return false;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--verbose")) {
        printlevel = DEBUG;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--quiet")) {
        printlevel = WARN;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-n") || 
               args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-nb") ||
               args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--narrowband")) {
        mode = 0;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-w") ||
               args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-wb") ||
               args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--wideband")) {
        mode = 1;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-u") ||
               args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-uwb") ||
               args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--ultra-wideband")) {
        mode = 2;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-q") || args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--quality")) {
        try {
          vbr_quality = Float.parseFloat(args[++i]);
          quality = (int) vbr_quality;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          usage();
          return false;
        }
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--complexity")) {
        try {
          complexity = Integer.parseInt(args[++i]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          usage();
          return false;
        }
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--nframes")) {
        try {
          nframes = Integer.parseInt(args[++i]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          usage();
          return false;
        }
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--vbr")) {
        vbr = true;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--vad")) {
        vad = true;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--dtx")) {
        dtx = true;
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--rate")) {
        try {
          sampleRate = Integer.parseInt(args[++i]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          usage();
          return false;
        }
      }
      else if (args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("--stereo")) {
        channels = 2;
      }
      else {
        usage();
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Prints the usage guidelines.
   */
  public static void usage()
  {
    version();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Usage: JSpeexEnc [options] input_file output_file");
    System.out.println("Where:");
    System.out.println("  input_file can be:" );
    System.out.println("    filename.wav  a PCM wav file");
    System.out.println("    filename.*    a raw PCM file (any extension other than .wav)");
    System.out.println("  output_file can be:");
    System.out.println("    filename.spx  an Ogg Speex file");
    System.out.println("    filename.wav  a Wave Speex file (beta!!!)");
    System.out.println("    filename.*    a raw Speex file");
    System.out.println("Options: -h, --help     This help");
    System.out.println("         -v, --version  Version information");
    System.out.println("         --verbose      Print detailed information");
    System.out.println("         --quiet        Print minimal information");
    System.out.println("         -n, -nb        Consider input as Narrowband (8kHz)");
    System.out.println("         -w, -wb        Consider input as Wideband (16kHz)");
    System.out.println("         -u, -uwb       Consider input as Ultra-Wideband (32kHz)");
    System.out.println("         --quality n    Encoding quality (0-10) default 8");
    System.out.println("         --complexity n Encoding complexity (0-10) default 3");
    System.out.println("         --nframes n    Number of frames per Ogg packet, default 1");
    System.out.println("         --vbr          Enable varible bit-rate (VBR)");
    System.out.println("         --vad          Enable voice activity detection (VAD)");
    System.out.println("         --dtx          Enable file based discontinuous transmission (DTX)");
    System.out.println("         if the input file is raw PCM (not a Wave file)");
    System.out.println("         --rate n       Sampling rate for raw input");
    System.out.println("         --stereo       Consider input as stereo");
    System.out.println("More information is available from: http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/");
    System.out.println("This code is a Java port of the Speex codec: http://www.speex.org/");
  }

  /**
   * Prints the version.
   */
  public static void version()
  {
    System.out.println(VERSION);
    System.out.println("using " + SpeexEncoder.VERSION);
    System.out.println(COPYRIGHT);
  }

  /**
   * Encodes a PCM file to Speex. 
   */
  public void  encode()
  {
      System.out.println("Value of Destination File is:= "+destFile);
          encode();
          System.out.println("Value of Destination File is:= " +srcFile +destFile);
  }

  /**
   * Encodes a PCM file to Speex. 
   * @param string
   * @param string2
   * @exception IOException */
  public void encode(final String string, final String string2)throws IOException
      {
    byte[] temp    = new byte[2560]; // stereo UWB requires one to read 2560b
    final int HEADERSIZE = 8;
    final String RIFF      = "RIFF";
    final String WAVE      = "WAVE";
    final String FORMAT    = "fmt ";
    final String DATA      = "data";
    final int WAVE_FORMAT_PCM = 0x0001;
    // Display info
    if (printlevel <= INFO) {
        version();
    }
    if (printlevel <= DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    if (printlevel <= DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("Input File: " );
    }
      try 
          (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(string))) 
      {
          if (srcFormat == FILE_FORMAT_WAVE) {
              // read the WAVE header
              dis.readFully(temp, 0, HEADERSIZE+4);
              // make sure its a WAVE header
              if (!RIFF.equals(new String(temp, 0, 4)) &&
                      !WAVE.equals(new String(temp, 8, 4))) 
              {
                  System.err.println("Not a WAVE file");
                  return;
              }
              // Read other header chunks
              dis.readFully(temp, 0, HEADERSIZE);
              String chunk = new String(temp, 0, 4);
              int size = readInt(temp, 4);
              while (!chunk.equals(DATA)) {
                  dis.readFully(temp, 0, size);
                  if (chunk.equals(FORMAT)) {
                      /*
                      typedef struct waveformat_extended_tag {
                      WORD wFormatTag; // format type
                      WORD nChannels; // number of channels (i.e. mono, stereo...)
                      DWORD nSamplesPerSec; // sample rate
                      DWORD nAvgBytesPerSec; // for buffer estimation
                      WORD nBlockAlign; // block size of data
                      WORD wBitsPerSample; // Number of bits per sample of mono data
                      WORD cbSize; // The count in bytes of the extra size
                      } WAVEFORMATEX;
                      */
                      if (readShort(temp, 0) != WAVE_FORMAT_PCM) {
                          System.err.println("Not a PCM file");
                          return;
                      }
                      channels = readShort(temp, 2);
                      sampleRate = readInt(temp, 4);
                      if (readShort(temp, 14) != 16) {
                          System.err.println("Not a 16 bit file " + readShort(temp, 18));
                          return;
                      }
                      // Display audio info
                      if (printlevel <= DEBUG) {
                          System.out.println("File Format: PCM wave");
                          System.out.println("Sample Rate: " + sampleRate);
                          System.out.println("Channels: " + channels);
                      }
                  }
                  dis.readFully(temp, 0, HEADERSIZE);
                  chunk = new String(temp, 0, 4);
                  size = readInt(temp, 4);
              }
              if (printlevel <= DEBUG) {
                  System.out.println("Data size: " + size);
              }
          }
          else {
              if (sampleRate < 0) {
                  switch (mode) {
                      case 0:
                          sampleRate = 8000;
                          break;
                      case 1:
                          sampleRate = 16000;
                          break;
                      case 2:
                          sampleRate = 32000;
                          break;
                      default:
                          sampleRate = 8000;
                          break;
                  }
              }
              // Display audio info
              if (printlevel <= DEBUG) {
                  System.out.println("File format: Raw audio");
                  System.out.println("Sample rate: " + sampleRate);
                  System.out.println("Channels: " + channels);
                  System.out.println("Data size: " + string.length());
              }
          }

          // Set the mode if it has not yet been determined
          if (mode < 0) {
              if (sampleRate < 100) { // Sample Rate has probably been given in kHz
                  sampleRate *= 1000;
              }
              if (sampleRate < 12000) {
                  mode = 0; // Narrowband
              } else if (sampleRate < 24000) {
                  mode = 1; // Wideband
              } else {
                  mode = 2; // Ultra-wideband
              }
          }
          // Construct a new encoder
          SpeexEncoder speexEncoder = new SpeexEncoder();
    SpeexEncoder speexEncoder1 = speexEncoder;
        if (complexity > 0) {
              speexEncoder1.setComplexity(complexity);
          }
          if (bitrate > 0) {

              speexEncoder1.setBitRate(bitrate);
           //   speexEncoder1.getEncoder().setBitRate(bitrate);
          }
          if (vbr) {
             // speexEncoder1.getEncoder().setVbr(vbr);
              if (vbr_quality > 0) {
                  speexEncoder1.setVbrQuality(vbr_quality);
              }
          }
          if (vad) {
              ( speexEncoder1).setVad(vad);
          }
          if (dtx) {
              ( speexEncoder1).setDtx(dtx);
          }

          // Display info
          if (printlevel <= DEBUG) {
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("Output File: " + string2);
              System.out.println("File format: Ogg Speex");
              System.out.println("Encoder mode: " + (mode==0 ? "Narrowband" : (mode==1 ? "Wideband" : "UltraWideband")));
              System.out.println("Quality: " + (vbr ? vbr_quality : quality));
              System.out.println("Complexity: " + complexity);
              System.out.println("Frames per packet: " + nframes);
              System.out.println("Variable bitrate: " + vbr);
              System.out.println("Voice activity detection: " + vad);
              System.out.println("Discontinouous Transmission: " + dtx);
          }
          // Open the file writer
          AudioFileWriter writer;
          if (destFormat == FILE_FORMAT_OGG) {
              writer = new OggSpeexWriter(mode, sampleRate, channels, nframes, vbr);
          }
          else if (destFormat == FILE_FORMAT_WAVE) {
              nframes = PcmWaveWriter.WAVE_FRAME_SIZES[mode-1][channels-1][quality];
              writer = new PcmWaveWriter(mode, quality, sampleRate, channels, nframes, vbr);
          }
          else {
              writer = new RawWriter();
          }
          writer.open(string2);
          writer.writeHeader("Encoded with: " + VERSION);
          int pcmPacketSize = 2 * channels * speexEncoder.getFrameSize();
          while (true) {
              dis.readFully(temp, 0, nframes*pcmPacketSize);
              for (int i=0; i<nframes; i++)
                  speexEncoder.processData(temp, i*pcmPacketSize, pcmPacketSize);
              int encsize = speexEncoder.getProcessedData(temp, 0);
              if (encsize > 0) {
                  writer.writePacket(temp, 0, encsize);
              }
          }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Converts Little Endian (Windows) bytes to an int (Java uses Big Endian).
     * @param data the data to read.
     * @param offset the offset from which to start reading.
     * @return the integer value of the reassembled bytes.
     */
    protected static int readInt(final byte[] data, final int offset)
    {
      return (data[offset] & 0xff) |
             ((data[offset+1] & 0xff) <<  8) |
             ((data[offset+2] & 0xff) << 16) |
             (data[offset+3] << 24); // no 0xff on the last one to keep the sign
    }

    /**
     * Converts Little Endian (Windows) bytes to an short (Java uses Big Endian).
     * @param data the data to read.
     * @param offset the offset from which to start reading.
     * @return the integer value of the reassembled bytes.
     */
    protected static int readShort(final byte[] data, final int offset)
    {
      return (data[offset] & 0xff) |
             (data[offset+1] << 8); // no 0xff on the last one to keep the sign
    }
  }
```

SpeexEncoder code

```
package org.xiph.speex;

/**
 * Main Speex Encoder class.
 * This class encodes the given PCM 16bit samples into Speex packets.
 *
 * @author Marc Gimpel, Wimba S.A. (mgimpel@horizonwimba.com)
 * @version $Revision: 1.6 $
 */
public class SpeexEncoder
{
  /**
   * Version of the Speex Encoder
   */
  public static final String VERSION = "Java Speex Encoder v0.9.7 ($Revision: 1.6 $)";

  private Encoder encoder;
  private Bits    bits;
  private float[] rawData;
  private int     sampleRate;
  private int     channels;
  private int     frameSize;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public SpeexEncoder()
  {
    bits = new Bits();
  }

  /**
   * Initialisation
   * @param mode       the mode of the encoder (0=NB, 1=WB, 2=UWB).
   * @param quality    the quality setting of the encoder (between 0 and 10).
   * @param sampleRate the number of samples per second.
   * @param channels   the number of audio channels (1=mono, 2=stereo, ...).
   * @return true if initialisation successful.
   */
  public boolean init(final int mode,
                      final int quality,
                      final int sampleRate,
                      final int channels)
  {
    switch (mode) {
      case 0:
        encoder = new NbEncoder();
        ((NbEncoder)encoder).nbinit();
        break;
//Wideband
      case 1:
        encoder = new SbEncoder();
        ((SbEncoder)encoder).wbinit();
        break;
      case 2:
        encoder = new SbEncoder();
        ((SbEncoder)encoder).uwbinit();
        break;
//*/
      default:
        return false;
    }

    /* initialize the speex decoder */
    encoder.setQuality(quality);

    /* set decoder format and properties */
    this.frameSize  = encoder.getFrameSize();
    this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
    this.channels   = channels;
    rawData         = new float[channels*frameSize];

    bits.init();
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the Encoder being used (Narrowband, Wideband or Ultrawideband).
   * @return the Encoder being used (Narrowband, Wideband or Ultrawideband).
   */
  public Encoder getEncoder()
  {
    return encoder;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the sample rate.
   * @return the sample rate.
   */
  public int getSampleRate()
  {
    return sampleRate;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of channels.
   * @return the number of channels.
   */
  public int getChannels()
  {
    return channels;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the size of a frame.
   * @return the size of a frame.
   */
  public int getFrameSize()
  {
    return frameSize;
  }

  /**
   * Pull the decoded data out into a byte array at the given offset
   * and returns the number of bytes of encoded data just read.
   * @param data
   * @param offset
   * @return the number of bytes of encoded data just read.
   */
  public int getProcessedData(final byte[] data, final int offset)
  {
    int size = bits.getBufferSize();
    System.arraycopy(bits.getBuffer(), 0, data, offset, size);
    bits.init();
    return size;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of bytes of encoded data ready to be read.
   * @return the number of bytes of encoded data ready to be read.
   */
  public int getProcessedDataByteSize()
  {
    return bits.getBufferSize();
  }

  /**
   * This is where the actual encoding takes place
   * @param data
   * @param offset
   * @param len
   * @return true if successful.
   */
  public boolean processData(final byte[] data,
                             final int offset,
                             final int len)
  {
    // converty raw bytes into float samples
    mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(data, offset, rawData, len, len);
    // encode the bitstream
    return processData(rawData, len/2);
  }

  /**
   * Encode an array of shorts.
   * @param data
   * @param offset
   * @param numShorts
   * @return true if successful.
   */
  public boolean processData(final short[] data,
                             final int offset,
                             final int numShorts)
  {
    int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize;
    if (numShorts != numSamplesRequired) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numShorts);
    }
    // convert shorts into float samples,
    for (int i=0; i<numShorts; i++) {
      rawData[i] = (float) data[offset + i ];
    }
    // encode the bitstream
    return processData(rawData, numShorts);
  }

  /**
   * Encode an array of floats.
   * @param data
   * @param numSamples
   * @return true if successful.
   */
  public boolean processData(final float[] data, final int numSamples)
  {
    int numSamplesRequired = channels * frameSize;
    if (numSamples != numSamplesRequired) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("SpeexEncoder requires " + numSamplesRequired + " samples to process a Frame, not " + numSamples );
    }
    // encode the bitstream
    if (channels==2) {
      Stereo.encode(bits, data, frameSize);
    }
   encoder.encode(bits, data);
    //System.out.println("THA VALUE OF BITS IS:" + bits);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Converts a 16 bit linear PCM stream (in the form of a byte array)
   * into a floating point PCM stream (in the form of an float array).
   * Here are some important details about the encoding:
   * <ul>
   * <li> Java uses big endian for shorts and ints, and Windows uses little Endian.
   *      Therefore, shorts and ints must be read as sequences of bytes and
   *      combined with shifting operations.
   * </ul>
   * @param pcm16bitBytes - byte array of linear 16-bit PCM formated audio.
   * @param offsetInput
   * @param samples - float array to receive the 16-bit linear audio samples.
   * @param offsetOutput
   * @param length
   */
  void mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(final byte[] pcm16bitBytes,
                                                   final int offsetInput,
                                                    float[] samples,
                                                   final int offsetOutput,
                                                   final int length)
  {
    if (pcm16bitBytes.length - offsetInput < 2 * length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient Samples to convert to floats");
    }
    System.out.println("the value is:" +samples);
    if (samples.length - offsetOutput < length) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient float buffer to convert the samples");
   }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      samples[offsetOutput+i] = (float)((pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput+2*i] & 0xff) | (pcm16bitBytes[offsetInput+2*i+1] << 8)); // no & 0xff at the end to keep the sign
    }

  }

public void setComplexity(int complexity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setVbrQuality(float vbr_quality) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setDtx(boolean dtx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setBitRate(int bitrate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setVad(boolean vad) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.xiph.speex.SpeexEncoder.mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float(SpeexEncoder.java:290)
at org.xiph.speex.SpeexEncoder.processData(SpeexEncoder.java:216)
at JSpeexEnc.encode(JSpeexEnc.java:541)
at JSpeexEnc.main(JSpeexEnc.java:170)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the sizes of the arrays that you're passing into `mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float`, and the number of iterations that your loops are doing, bearing in mind that in Java, arrays start from zero.

Comment: I'd recommend running the code and putting a breakpoint in at the start of the `mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float` method, and depending on your IDE you should be able to see the size of the array. If you're not using one, you could just print the values to console.

Comment: @ Yann4 In the mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float method I have checked the values of all parameters.. The value of samples is coming out to be null. how to rectify it further. please suggest

Comment: As in you're passing an null array and attempting to iterate through it? What is the value of offsetOutput and length?

Comment: @ Yann4 The value of offsetOutput and length is both 0... how to avoid passing an null array and attempting to iterate through it.

Comment: I thought you got the answer, sorry. I think that you're attempting to print out a null float array in `mapPcm16bitLittleEndian2Float`. In the line `System.out.println("the value is:" +samples);`, you need to select a specific item in the array, as in `samples[i]`, for whatever `i` needs to be

Comment: @ Yann4 sir actually I am very much confused about the array running for the samples for which it is providing null value.I am not understanding that where the null value us provided and where it is passing??